# exim - Tainted filename for search - sender verify defer for failed to expand

Tags: email, spam, exim

discovered today this mailserver problem, and because have not written exim myself, can't debug it X-D

also: is this normal?

```
host zen.spamhaus.org
ping zen.spamhaus.org
ping: zen.spamhaus.org: No address associated with hostname
```

spamhaus.org does still exist,

but zen.spamhaus.org seems to have been removed?

```
===== trying to receive mail =====

==> /var/log/exim/main.log <== 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 DNS list lookup defer (probably timeout) for 9.67.15.31.zen.spamhaus.org: assumed not in list 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 Tainted filename for search: '/etc/exim/domains/sendingDomain.com/aliases' 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 H=berlin.freifunk.net [31.15.67.9] F=<berlin-bounces@berlin.freifunk.net> temporarily rejected RCPT <user@sendingDomain.com>:
failed to expand "${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}": NULL 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 Tainted filename for search: '/etc/exim/domains/sendingDomain.com/aliases' 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 H=ip-109-42-0-98.web.vodafone.de ([192.168.0.222]) [109.42.0.98] sender verify defer for <user@sendingDomain.com>: failed to expand "${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}": NULL 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 H=ip-109-42-0-98.web.vodafone.de ([192.168.0.222]) [109.42.0.98] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no F=<user@sendingDomain.com> A=dovecot_plain:user@sendingDomain.com temporarily rejected RCPT <user@receiver.com>: Could not complete sender verify
   
==> /var/log/exim/panic.log <== 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 Tainted filename for search: '/etc/exim/domains/sendingDomain.com/aliases' 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 Tainted filename for search: '/etc/exim/domains/sendingDomain.com/aliases' 

==> /var/log/exim/reject.log <== 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 H=berlin.freifunk.net [31.15.67.9] F=<berlin-bounces@berlin.freifunk.net> temporarily rejected RCPT <user@sendingDomain.com>: failed to expand "${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}": NULL 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 H=ip-109-42-0-98.web.vodafone.de ([192.168.0.222]) [109.42.0.98] sender verify defer for <user@sendingDomain.com>: failed to expand "${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}": NULL 
2020-07-20 10:39:51 H=ip-109-42-0-98.web.vodafone.de ([192.168.0.222]) [109.42.0.98] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no F=<user@sendingDomain.com> A=dovecot_plain:user@sendingDomain.com temporarily rejected RCPT <user@receiver.com>: Could not complete sender verify
```

is this the end of the mail world?

after all: mail is such an important (still most used messenger service) yet error and security prone system (a lot of hacks/trojan horses come as attachment:word.doc)

```
# searching exim config dir
grep -r -i -E --color=auto /etc/exim/ "zen.spamhaus.org"

# found this
/etc/exim/dnsbl.conf

# reveals:
cat /etc/exim/dnsbl.conf
bl.spamcop.net
zen.spamhaus.org

# removed the zen.spamhaus.org
vim /etc/exim/dnsbl.conf

# reboot
# trying again
```

... no luck, can't send or receive mail, still problem "verify sender".

vim /etc/exim/exim.conf

```
aliases:
  driver = redirect
  headers_add = X-redirected: yes
  data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}
  require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases
  redirect_router = dnslookup
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  unseen
```

Comment: Could you post the part of the config where you try to use the expansion which fails?

Comment: thanks for your comment, updated the above question to include the info Lacek requested.

Answer (score 3):

https://jedi.school.nz/eximfix.html says the correct format is:

```
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain_data}}
```

Exim 4.94 (e.g. Ubuntu 20.04) introduced "tainting" of variables. In places where "tainted" is complained, you might need to add _data to end of local_part or domain:

```
{$local_part} -> {$local_part_data}
{$domain} -> {$domain_data}
```

However, in this case only domain needs to be changed. More info from
https://mox.sh/sysadmin/tainted-filename-errors-in-exim-4.94/

Comment: See also: https://blog.sourcepole.ch/2022/08/23/untainting-vdom-alias-lookups/

Answer (score 1):

`zen.spamhaus.org` does not have an IP address, and it is expected. To check if an address is blacklisted, you should query `(ip address).zen.spamhaus.org` (with the IP address parts reversed), and check if it yields a result.

The logs indicate that the query is timed out, which suggests that you made too much queries to `spamhaus.org`. Nevertheless, this failure does not mean the mail is rejected (as indicated by "assumed not in list").

Your problem is that you try to construct a filename from the parts of the incoming mail, and using this file for a query, however, the file is never opened, because `exim` thinks it is "tainted".
In `exim`, a "tainted" anything is an expansion what comes directly from the sender. Anything the sender directly supplies is considered unreliable, so in a router, opening a file pointed by an expansion of tainted data is forbidden.

You can circumvent it by using the tainted data for some kind of lookup, which yields a non-tainted data, which, in turn, can be used for addressing a file.

Another solution would be to use only one `aliases` file, which is fixed, and you don't need to use sender-supplied strings for locating it. Or perhaps have the aliases stored in a database of some kind, and lookup from the database.